# A durable rubber type material that can flex easily but return to its original shape very fast

Tags: materials, flexures

I'm looking for a durable rubber type of material for a guitar pick holder. The material I'm looking for will need to have flexibility to pick individual notes of a guitar, but needs to return to its original shape/position as fast as possible for picking faster notes.

I've tried vulcanized rubber sheets of different thicknesses (1 mm to 4 mm), it has good flexibility, but returning to its original shape is very slow.

The material from a bouncy ball is the closest material I can imagine for what I need, but I need something in a sheet form.

Comment: Did I misread? You hold the pick in a holder? Why not just hold the pick directly? If it's actually the pick you're talking about, stainless steel picks exist.

Comment: If you want to buy rubber in small quantities, you would be well served to try McMaster-Carr: https://www.mcmaster.com/rubber/rubber/

Comment: If you can come up with what needs to give and what needs to spring back fast, you may be able to come up with  a geometric solution.  If you think of a tennis ball, it is a rubber exterior and air interior.  Similarly the pick itself can serve as a lever while the rubber enacts a moment instead of a more uniform pressure.  Slow springback of rubber can thus be amplified by the lever.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem: To make rubber strong, it has carbon black mixed into it (as in car tires) But the carbon black also slows down the springback of the rubber. For strength and quick springback, try either *urethane* rubber or *silicone* rubber.

Comment: ... and the degree of hardness is measured on the Shore (Durometer) scale. There are plenty of articles on the subject available on the web.